# Why do electrons form Cooper pairs below certain temperature?

Tags: solid-state-physics, supersymmetry, bose-einstein-condensate

*Just a heads up - please make this answer understandable to around 1st year degree level physics - not PhD research. So I can understand it - thanks.*

1) In solid state physics, why is it that below a certain temperature (KE of the electrons) do the electrons form Cooper Pairs / a condensate via BCS Theory?

I know its something to do with their KE being less than the attraction energy between the two electrons.

But a book i'm readings says its 'at low temperatures the electrons prefer to condense into pairs and make the superconducting state, and this is because it costs them less energy to do so'.
So according to the book - why is it that above a certain temperature it costs them more energy to form a cooper pair (instead of staying as individual entities)?? And what does this have to do with their attraction.

2) Lastly, why is there an attraction at all at any temperature - aren't the electrons both negatively charged?